# Expectation using Monte Carlo explaination

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, statistics, expected-value

Although Monte Carlo (MC) is an easy-implementating algorithm, but I'm still confused with the sampling theory behind it.

Especially, the MC can approximate an expectation with

$$
\int f(X(\omega))\mathbb{P}(d\omega) \approx \sum_i^N f(X(\omega_i)),
$$
where $(X, \Omega, \mathbb{P})$ the probability space, and $\omega_i$ some samples from sampling space.

My first intuition is to use quadrature in a deterministic way, i.e., Gauss-Hermite. Although it would be great to compute it with evaluation of samples, but I don't quite understand why summation over samples work here.

**My question is, why can we calculate the above integral with that summation using *samples*? What are the theory and mathematical formulations behind it?**

---

My attempt: 
Recall the definition of integral. Suppose that $X$ and $f$ are simple: $X=\sum_i^Ka_i \chi_{A_i}$, where $A_i = X^{-1}\{a_i\}$ and $\chi$ the indicator function. Thus $\int f(X(\omega))\mathbb{P}(d\omega) = \sum_i^Ka_i\mathbb{P}(A_i)\approx1/N \sum_i^N f(X(\omega_i))$, where $a_i\in A_i$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The secret lies in strong law of large numbers $(SLLN)$

Consider $\mathbb{E}\{X \} = \int x p_X(x) dx$

If we could get many i.i.d samples $x_1, x_2, ..., x_N$ from the distribution $p_X$, i.e. each $x_i \sim p_X$, then by the law of large numbers, we have as $N \to \infty$, $$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_i \to \mathbb{E}[X] = \int x p_X(x) dx$$

So basically, we have $$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N x_i \to \int x p_X(x) \, \,\, \,\, \,\, \,\, \,\, \,\, \,\, \,\, \,\, \,\, \,\, \, (SLLN)$$

So consider $\int f (x) dx = \int \frac{ f(x)}{p_X(x)} p_X(x) dx$ assuming $p_X(x) \neq 0$ over the interval of integration.

Now, if we have i.i.d samples $x_1, ..., x_N$, then by analogy with $(SLLN)$, we have, as $N$ becomes large,

$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{f(x_i)}{p_X(x_i)} \to \int \frac{ f(x)}{p_X(x)} p_X(x) dx = \int f(x) dx$$

So we are estimating the integral $\int f(x) dx$ with $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{f(x_i)}{p_X(x_i)}$.

The choice of $p_X$ is arbitrary. The variance of the estimate depends crucially on the choice of the sampling distribution. Related concepts are **importance sampling** and **variance reduction**.

Comment: Absolutely, +1.

Comment: When adapting $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N x_i \to \mathbb{E}[X]$ to a more general case, $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^N f(x_i) \to \mathbb{E}[f(X)]$, what is the conditon of $f$ in order to use this? ($f$ is measurable?)

Comment: @MrPickles You just need to satisfy the prerequisites of the strong law of large numbers. Let's call $Y = f(X)$. Is $\mathbb{E}[Y]$ well defined? Finite variance $\text{var}(Y) < \infty$ condition also makes the convergence faster. And yes, $Y$ is a random variable so by definition, $f$ must be measurable.